# How to resume the coredump file as a process？

Tags: gdb, lldb, coredump

Suppose there are coredump, executable files and dwarf files locally.

If the process can be reloaded locally, can it be on a remote machine?

I know how to use `lldb -c coredump` to load a coredump. But the coredump loaded in this way seems to be different from the usual `lldb attached process`. Command `expr` is not really support.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about. You can load coredump on remote machine as well. You can also attach to a process on remote machine with gdbserver. However you can't resume a process from coredump either locally or remote.

Answer (score 0):

> How to resume the coredump file as a process?

That's impossible.

For one thing, all file descriptors from the old process have been closed. For another, the process and thread IDs may now belong to some other process.

Comment: I know of a couple experiments with "reviving" core files; not enough to get them to actually continue to run, but at least alive enough that the debugger could run expressions in them.  That would be desirable since there are a some debugging techniques that use expressions for introspection.  But even that is quite tricky to pull off reliably, and all the experiments I know about were abandoned.

Comment: @JimIngham Actually I just want to use `expression`,  can you explain in more detail.

Comment: To get expressions to run in a core file you have to convince the kernel to load the core file as the memory and thread state for a new process, where the threads are actually live (so you can set a pc into the JIT-ed expression code and tell the kernel to run it.)  That is hard to do in a way that doesn't panic the kernel or cause some other bad side effects, since you really can't revive all the resources it used.  I have seen two separate efforts to get this working, and both of them failed to produce a sufficiently stable process to be worth continuing the effort.

Comment: lldb is able to interpret (as opposed to JIT and run) simple expressions.  In fact, it always tries to interpret expressions if it can, you don't need to do anything to get it to do that.  So you can run some expressions when attached to a core file, but not expressions that require execution (e.g. allocations, function calls.)